# Heroku PostrgreSQL client doesn't find relations

Tags: postgresql, heroku, case-sensitive, identifier

I am using **Heroku** and his **PostgreSQL** addon. When I login to **pg:psql** and do:

```
SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema='public';
```

I see all my tables:

```
Users
Cities
Registrations
```

Which is expected.
But when I do:

```
select * from users;
```

Result is :

```
ERROR:  relation "users" does not exist
LINE 1: select * from users;
```

Does anyone knows what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Classic problem with mixed case identifiers.

Try:

```
select * from "Users";
```

Read the chapter [**Identifiers and Key Words**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS) in the manual.
To make your life easier only use legal, lower case identifiers, or you have to double-quote the names.