# Fastest way to insert data to database for one to many relationship

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql, insert, one-to-many

I am looking for a fastest way to insert data into database.

Currently I have 2 tables which is "User" and "User_Detail".
One "User" can has many "User_detail"
Example:

In database,we have the record of Age and mail for user "John".

User table

```
|Name     |
|---------|
| John    | 
| Jason   |  
| Wilson  |
```

User_Detail table

```
| Usr_Name| Property | Value  |
|---------+----------+--------|
| John    | Age      | 12     |
| John    | mail     | gmail  |
| Wilson  | Age      | 31     |
```

I would like to write a query to add "uni" to ALL of the users.
The result will become like this.

User_Detail table

```
| Usr_Name | Property | Value  |
|----------+----------+--------|
| John     | Age      | 12     |
| John     | mail     | gmail  |
| John     | Uni      | 00000  |
| Wilson   | Age      | 31     |
| Wilson   | Uni      | 00000  |
| Jason    | Uni      | 00000  |
```

Is there any suggestions or ideas on how to insert data ?
I need the fastest way to do it, as I have around 10k users in my USER table.
It can be any language or database query, as long as it can be very fast to insert the record to database.

Comment: Where are you getting the value from from the User_Detail table?

Comment: Show us some ways and we'll tell you which is fastest

Comment: Please consider the [formatting aids provided here on SO.](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: How many properties? Do they change dynamically? If they are not too many and stable, consider a normalized schema instead of EAV storage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, consider normalizing your schema. Here is an [in-depth discussion of EAV storage on dba.SE](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/20759/is-there-a-name-for-this-database-structure).

With your given design, this does the job:

```
INSERT INTO "User_Detail" ("Usr_Name", "Property", "Value")
SELECT "Name", 'Uni', '0000'
FROM   "User";
```

In Postgres, I would also advise [not to use mixed-case identifiers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22886505/heroku-postrgresql-client-doesnt-find-relations/22887246#22887246).

Comment: Hi Erwin, Thanks for the help. It works well on my database. :)

Answer (score 0):

To insert a value in, just do a simple insert query.

```
INSERT INTO `User_detail` (`User_name`, 'Property`, `Value')
SELECT `Name`, 'H/P', 50012 FROM `Users`
```

To make the inserted value be something different, you need to change that hard coded value 50012 to something that resolves to the number you want there.

Comment: Hi LeeG, actually the value for "uni" is hard coded. It will be the same value for all of the users

Comment: Hi LeeG, I am not really understand on the query . If use the query above 'select name from user' it will always be the same user right?

Comment: This is non-standard MySQL syntax, and incorrect at that (check your backticks).